# Horizontal Divs with One of Them Taking Remainder of Space

Tags: html

Classic question on laying out 2 divs horizontally within a parent div with a slight twist - How can one of the divs have a fixed width (e.g. 100px) and the other taking up the remaining space (e.g. 100%) *on the same line*?

```
<div>
    <div id="div1" style="float: left; width: 100px; background-color: #ff0000;">
    &nbsp;
    </div>    
    <div id="div2" style="float: left; width: 100%; background-color: #00ff00;">
    &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/mKH46/2/

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mKH46/4/)

There is slight change in your code

```
<div>
    <div id="div1" style="float: left; width: 100px; background-color: #ff0000;">
     &nbsp;
    </div>    
    <div id="div2" style="width: 100%; background-color: #00ff00;">
     &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for something like that?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mKH46/5/)

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
}
#div1{
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
#div2{
    background: green;
}
```